# Can anyone please tell me that how to convert image to base64 in postman

Tags: postman

Can anyone please tell me that how to convert image to base64 in postman?
I have used get method to retrieve the pht with http request, response i got image,
But i neei need base64 string instead of that image

Do anyone having the idea about this